# Group items and return common part

Tags: sql

I have a table Person

```
Name  | Surname  | City | Street | Some Common Field|
A1    |    B1    |  C1  |   S1   |   1             |
A2    |    B2    |  C1  |   S1   |   1             |
A3    |    B3    |  C2  |   S2   |   2             |
A4    |    B4    |  C2  |   S2   |   2             |
A5    |    B5    |  C3  |   S3   |   3             |
```

And I need in results

```
Count |City | Street | Some Field|
2     | C1  |   S1   |     1     |
2     | C2  |   S2   |     2     |
1     | C3  |   S3   |     3     |
```

How can I get it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS Cnt,
       City,
       Street,
       SomeField
FROM   YourTable
GROUP  BY City,
          Street,
          SomeField
```